# Can gynecomastia breast tissues be dissolved?

Tags: zinc, hormonal-imbalance, estrogen, gynecomastia-man-boobs

If one takes zinc and vitamin D then the T levels increase. 
So oestrogen must decrease and thus gynecomastia goes away.

But this [site](https://www.gynecomastia.org/smf/index.php?topic=23533.0) says that the breast tissues can never be dissolved even if the hormones are balanced. Is it true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of gynaecomastia?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/16804/how-to-get-rid-of-gynaecomastia)

Comment: Please edit your original question on gynaecomastia with this question.  You can then flag the original question to morderators for re-opening.  The re-opening will go to a vote and if you follow this advice you would get my vote to re-open

Comment: @ChrisRogers His first question was a blatant request for medical advice. It shouldn't be reopened. This question is okay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce weight-caused man boobs (psuedogynaecomastia)?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/how-to-reduce-weight-caused-man-boobs-psuedogynaecomastia)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not true that the breast tissue caused by gynecomastia can never go away. According to the [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/gynecomastia/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20351799) (emphasis mine):

> **Most cases of gynecomastia regress over time without treatment.**
>   However, if gynecomastia is caused by an underlying condition, such as
>   hypogonadism, malnutrition or cirrhosis, that condition may need
>   treatment. If you're taking medications that can cause gynecomastia,
>   your doctor may recommend stopping them or substituting another
>   medication.

So the first step in dealing with gynecomastia is to identify and treat the factor causing it. That may mean treating an underlying condition or it may mean stopping or changing medications. Once that's been addressed all that's needed is time, and the time needed can be measured in months or even years.

If the breast tissue doesn't go away despite appropriate treatment and the sufferer finds the tissue intolerable, two options remain: medication and surgery. Again, according to Mayo:

> **Medications**
>
> Medications used to treat breast cancer and other conditions, such as
>   tamoxifen (Soltamox), raloxifene (Evista) and aromatase inhibitors
>   (Arimidex), may be helpful for some men with gynecomastia. Although
>   these medications are approved by the Food and Drug Administration,
>   they have not been approved specifically for this use.
>
> **Surgery to remove excess breast tissue**
>
> If you still have significant
>   bothersome breast enlargement despite initial treatment or
>   observation, your doctor may advise surgery. Two gynecomastia surgery
>   options are:
>
> **Liposuction**. This surgery removes breast fat, but not the breast gland
>   tissue itself.
>
> **Mastectomy**. This type of surgery removes the breast
>   gland tissue. The surgery is often done endoscopically, meaning only
>   small incisions are used. This less invasive type of surgery involves
>   less recovery time.

Answer (score 1):

First, vitamin D supplementation does not seem to increase testosterone levels. Most high quality trials see either no increase, or a very very small one:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32446600/

Second, zinc might negate a transient exercise-induced decrease in testosterone. There is no evidence this is clinically meaningful:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17984944/
And (short-term) zinc deficiency might decrease testosterone. So in case you're zinc deficient, supplementation is (of course) wise.
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1609752/

Treating gynecomastia is a whole different ball game. This is either done by surgery or sometimes off-label with endocrine treatment. Endocrine treatment refers to drugs that counteract estrogenic action. Since estrogenic action lies at the root of gynecomastia development.

Several of such drugs have been tested in clinical research, including: Tamoxifen (Nolvadex), clomiphene (Clomid), raloxifene (Evista) and Anastrozol (Arimidex).

Of these drugs, clomiphene and anastrozol don't seem so effective against it. Of raloxifene only one trial is available which suggests good results. However, it's a low quality trial.

Finally, a lot of research demonstrates that tamoxifen (Nolvadex) is effective against gynecomastia.

More details can be found here in case you're interested: https://peterbond.org/post/endocrine-treatment-of-gynecomastia